# Batch Printing Documents via Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, adobe-reader

I have a routine job of printing around 40 or so pages a few times a month. These sheets are a mix of word and pdf documents linked from an excel document. I want to print them is a specific sequence.

I would like to automate this task. If possible, I would also like to do it in a way that is easy to understand for others to understand.

My first option is to use a VBA macro, but this is not easy for others to understand. I don't have much experience with visual basic, but I am comfortable in Java and C++, so I imagine I could pick it up.

The second option is to format all the links as commands in excel and use those to make a batch file. This has the disadvantage of having to copy and paste all the links. I am also unsure whether it will fail to deal with so many commands at the same time. I know that adobe reader needs files sent one at a time for printint. Sumatra reader will allow me to send a batch (in theory)

I imagine this is quite a common task for offices.

Are there any alternatives I'm missing that would better suit my requirements?

Comment: Give us a look at what you've already tried rather than just asking for a solution, please.

Comment: I've clearly explained what I have already tried. Adding that would serve no purpose that I could think of. I am looking for other ideas.

Comment: I don't see any examples of how you've implemented those ideas, just what you think about them. If you don't have a solution in mind, we can't do that for you. If you're looking for a piece of software, try softwarerecs.SE

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for alternative solutions to what I have already come up with. Is that not within the scope of Super User?

Comment: It's a little [open ended](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) for this site, the way it is asked. It'd be different if you said "hey I wrote this VBA but it has problems x y z" - that would show you put effort into solving your problem, but also open to completely different solutions

Comment: I've made more progress using VBA macros. Once I have something working well, I'll post my solution.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks for your help so far. To be clear, is asking for an alternative outside of VBA and batch files is too broad? How could I make this question more specific without knowing an alternative myself?

Comment: Just show evidence of what you did try - say you wrote a macro or part of a macro and it's not working - you can ask how to fix it *and* explain what it is you're trying to do, in which case there may be a better way to do it than a macro

Comment: I can do that. Should I write. A new question or update this one?

Comment: Improve this question and then it can be reopened

Answer (score 1):

Failing anything else, I would write a macro that saves all the different files as PDF files.  Then merge the PDF files together (With the other PDF Files).  And print them as a single large PDF file.  Debenu QuickPDF has free tools to merge PDF Files.  Scriptable with PowerShell I believe.  But it hardly seems like an Excel Problem.  FWIW